# Sql Exeption: Invalid column name "NormalizedUserName..." in existing .net framework identiy db used by .net core project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-4.0, asp.net-identity

I have a projct in .Net Framework. i use .Net Framework and .Net Framework Asp.net Identity. There is no problem here...

Now I am creating a new project. It's a .Net Core 2.2 Project that must connect to the existing database. I cannot change the structure of the database. I have scaffolded the db withi this command

```
Scaffold-DbContext -Connection "..." -Provider Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models -Context MyDatabaseContext -Tables "Profile", <other_tables_no_identity>
```

So the database has been scaffolded, then I modified manually the following files

1. I have added `IdentityUser` to `Profile` entity

```
   public partial class Profile : IdentityUser {...}
```

2. I have modified the `OnModelCreating` in this way:

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
 {
     //I have added this lines
     base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder); 

     modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>(entity =>
     {
         entity.ToTable("BaseProfile");

         entity.Property(e => e.Id)
                 .HasMaxLength(128)
                 .ValueGeneratedNever();

         entity.Property(e => e.Email)
                 .IsRequired()
                 .HasMaxLength(256);

         entity.Property(e => e.UserName)
                 .IsRequired()
                 .HasMaxLength(256);
         });

     modelBuilder.Entity<Profile>(entity =>
     {
         entity.ToTable("Profile");

         entity.HasIndex(e => e.Id)
                 .HasName("IX_Id");

         entity.Property(e => e.Id)
                 .HasMaxLength(128)
                 .ValueGeneratedNever();

         entity.Property(e => e.CreationDate).HasColumnType("datetime");

         entity.Property(e => e.LastAccessDate).HasColumnType("datetime");

         entity.Property(e => e.Rating).HasColumnType("decimal(18, 2)");
     });

     modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<string>>().ToTable("ProfileRoleAssociation");
     modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin<string>>().ToTable("ProfileLoginAssociation");
     modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim<int>>().ToTable("ProfileClaimAssociation");
     modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("ProfileRole");


 }
```

I have copied that lines from the old .Net Framework project... But when I try to make a login I obtain this error:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>   SqlException: Invalid column name 'NormalizedUserName'.
>   Invalid column name 'AccessFailedCount'.
>   Invalid column name 'ConcurrencyStamp'.
>   Invalid column name 'Email'.
>   Invalid column name 'EmailConfirmed'.
>   Invalid column name 'LockoutEnabled'.
>   Invalid column name 'LockoutEnd'.
>   Invalid column name 'NormalizedEmail'.
>   Invalid column name 'NormalizedUserName'.
>   Invalid column name 'PasswordHash'.
>   Invalid column name 'PhoneNumber'.
>   Invalid column name 'PhoneNumberConfirmed'.
>   Invalid column name 'SecurityStamp'.
>   Invalid column name 'TwoFactorEnabled'.
>   Invalid column name 'UserName'.

The column name `NormalizedUserName` does not exists. But the others yes.

[image]

What's wrong? Thank you

**EDIT**

I understood the problem is about inheritance. It look for columns inside `Profile` table instead of `BaseProfile`... but I still do not understand how to solve it.

Comment: According to existing code, it is not easy to reproduce the issue .Could you share the existing database query file and the complete code of  `Profile ` and `DbContext`?

Comment: you are right... it was no so immediate.... I am writing the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has been a bit complicating, because of I could not modify the original .net framework application....

Here the situation in the old .net framework project:
I have a `profile` class inherits from `IdentityUser`.

```
public class Profile : IdentityUser { ... }
```

Then `OnModelCreating` I have this

```
var baseProfile = modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>().ToTable("BaseProfile");
modelBuilder.Entity<Profile>().ToTable("Profile");
modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().ToTable("ProfileRoleAssociation");
modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().ToTable("ProfileLoginAssociation");
modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>().ToTable("ProfileClaimAssociation");
modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("ProfileRole");
```

So, that was the initial situation I could not change.

Well, In my new .net core project I have launche this command in the `PackageManager Console`:

```
    Scaffold-DbContext -Connection {connection_string} -Provider Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models -Context MyContext -Tables "Profile", "BaseProfile", <other_tables>
```

Note `BaseProfile` is not an entity in the .net framework. And note that for some reason, the command does not generate the properties defined in the `IdentityUser` class. So, I have modified the auto-generated class as following:

```
public partial class BaseProfile : IdentityUser
{
    public override string Id { get; set; }
    public override string Email { get; set; }
    public override bool EmailConfirmed { get; set; }
    public override string PasswordHash { get; set; }
    public override string SecurityStamp { get; set; }
    public override string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public override bool PhoneNumberConfirmed { get; set; }
    public override bool TwoFactorEnabled { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LockoutEndDateUtc { get; set; }
    public override bool LockoutEnabled { get; set; }
    public override int AccessFailedCount { get; set; }
    public override string UserName { get; set; }

    public override string NormalizedEmail { get { return this.Email.ToUpperInvariant(); } }
    public override string NormalizedUserName { get { return this.UserName.ToUpperInvariant(); } }
    public virtual Profile Profile { get; set; }
}
```

I have modified the `BaseProfile` so that it inherits from `IdentityUser`. All properties auto-generated by scaffolding command and defined in `IdentityUser` class have been overriden. Do not delete them, even if they are defined in `IdentityUser` would not be binded to the database.
I also created two new properties:

```
public override string NormalizedEmail { get { return this.Email.ToUpperInvariant(); } }
public override string NormalizedUserName { get { return this.UserName.ToUpperInvariant(); } }
```

`Normalized*` properties donot exist in old version of MS Identity. But they are necessary for the new one. That two properties need to let users to login. In fact the input of the user during login is compared with that two properties. Well, it is not the most correct the implementation of that properties. But for my culture is ok.

Finally, `OnModelCreating` I have added theese lines:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<BaseProfile>(entity =>
{
    entity.ToTable("BaseProfile");
    entity.Ignore(e => e.LockoutEnd);
    entity.Ignore(e => e.ConcurrencyStamp);
    entity.Ignore(e => e.NormalizedEmail);
    entity.Ignore(e => e.NormalizedUserName);
    entity.Ignore(e => e.LockoutEnd);
});
```

That are properties not in old version of Identity, but only in the new one.

Comment: I have been using your solution for more than a year up until I upgraded to .Net Core 3.1, then it stopped working due to some breaking changes in the newest framework...