# Using existing .Net Identity database in .NET CORE application

Tags: asp.net-core, identity

im new to identity core and am trying to create a mvc app using .Net Core 3.1.1 and hit a roadblock on identity.

My toughest restriction is that I need to use the old Identity database from an old MVC5 app. The app is in use and this means the **table structure cannot be changed**.

Followed the steps described in [Sql Exeption: Invalid column name "NormalizedUserName..." in existing .net framework identiy db used by .net core project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61456482/sql-exeption-invalid-column-name-normalizedusername-in-existing-net-frame)

Got Usermanager and models set up in startup:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
      {
          services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
              options.UseSqlServer(
                  Configuration.GetConnectionString("RaksaConnection")));
         
          services.AddDbContext<RaksaDbContext>(options=>
          options.UseSqlServer(
              Configuration.GetConnectionString("RaksaConnection")));

          services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>()
      .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
      .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
          //services.AddTransient <UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
          services.AddControllersWithViews();
          services.AddRazorPages();
      }
```

And models copied over from older site:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public ApplicationUser()
        {
            this.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        private string PF_FName;
        private string PF_FNameAndCompany;
        public int? NeptonUserId { get; set; }
        public string NeptonUserName { get; set; }
        public int? NeptonUserPersonnelNumber { get; set; }
        public virtual Guid CompanyDataId { get; set; }
        public override string UserName { get; set; }
        public override string NormalizedEmail { get { return this.Email.ToUpperInvariant(); } }
        public override string NormalizedUserName { get { return this.UserName.ToUpperInvariant(); } }
        public DateTime? LockoutEndDateUtc { get; set; }
        private string PF_CompanyVat { get; set; }
        private string PF_JobTitleValue { get; set; }
        private DateTime PF_AccountCreated { get; set; }
        public bool GIG_worker { get; set; }
        public DateTime? LastLogin { get; set; }
        public int CommLevelId { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Nimi")]
        public string FullName
        {
            get
            {
                this.PF_FName = FirstName + " " + LastName;
                return this.PF_FName;
            }
        }
        
        public DateTime AccountCreated
        {
            get
            {
                return this.PF_AccountCreated;
            }
            set
            {
                this.PF_AccountCreated = value;
            }
        }
        private bool PF_Isrejected { get; set; }
        public bool IsRejected
        {
            get
            {
                return this.PF_Isrejected;
            }
            set
            {
                this.PF_Isrejected = value;
            }
        }
        public bool Active { get; set; }
        public string JobTitle
        {
            get
            {
                return this.PF_JobTitleValue;
            }
            set
            {
                this.PF_JobTitleValue = value;
            }
        }
    }
public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole
{
        public ApplicationRole()
        {
            base.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        }
        public ApplicationRole(string name) : this()
        {
            base.Name = name;
        }
        public ICollection<Permission> Permissions { get; set; }
    }
    
public class Permission
    {
        public Permission()
        {
            this.PermissionId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            this.RolesWithPermission = new HashSet<ApplicationRole>();
        }

        public string PermissionId { get; set; }
        public string PermissionDescription { get; set; }

        public ICollection<ApplicationRole> RolesWithPermission;
       
    }
}
```

Can get the usermanager to list the users just fine, but SignInManager compalains about NormalizedUsername field:

```
    InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'DbSet<ApplicationUser>
.Where(a => a.NormalizedUserName == __normalizedUserName_0)' could not be translated.
 Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation 
explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), 
or ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
```

Don't know where to go next, do I have to customize signInmanager or is there a more simple solution?

Comment: Did some digging and looks like I have to override some methods on the UserStore to get login to work.

Comment: " Can get the usermanager to list the users just fine, but SignInManager compalains about NormalizedUsername field"  Could you share your code about how to list ? It may cause the error.

Comment: Usermanager.Users.ToList() works, although just noticed finding a single user does not. complains about Normalized fields.

Comment: the code like ? Can you show me it ?

Comment: @QingGuo got it figured out, by extending UserStore and RoleStore and changing the methods where Normalized fields were used